Show that there exists a measurable function $f:R\rightarrow R$ such that $f(x)≤\alpha$ on $E_\alpha$ and $f(x)\geq \alpha$ on $R∖E_\alpha$ .
Suppose that for each $\alpha \in R$, there exists a measurable set $E_\alpha \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that:
$$\alpha < \beta, \text{ then } E_\alpha \subset E_\beta$$
$$\cap_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}} E_\alpha = \emptyset$$
$$\cup_{\alpha \in \mathbb{R}} E_\alpha = \mathbb{R}$$
Show that there exists a measurable function $ f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ such that $f(x) \leq \alpha$ on $E_\alpha$
and $f(x) \geq \alpha$ on $\mathbb{R} \setminus E_\alpha$.
Is my proof correct?:
Define $f(x)= \sup\{\alpha : x \not \in  E_\alpha\}$. To show that this function is well-defined note that $x\not \in E_\alpha$ for some $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ otherwise $x\in \cap_\alpha E_\alpha=\emptyset$. Also $f(x)\not= \infty$ since $x\in \cup_\alpha E_\alpha =\mathbb{R}$. Now to show $f(x)\geq \alpha$ on $\mathbb{R}\setminus E_\alpha$, take $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus E_\alpha$. Since $x\not\in E_\alpha$, $f(x)\geq\alpha$. We claim that $f^{-1}(-\infty,\alpha)= E_\alpha$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ (thus showing $f(x)$ is measurable and $f(x)\leq \alpha$ on $E_a$). Take $x\in f^{-1}(-\infty,\alpha)$. Since $f(x)< \alpha$, $x\in E_\alpha$ (by contrapositive $x\not\in E_\alpha$ implies $f(x)\geq \alpha$). Take $x\in E_\alpha$. We have that $x\in E_\beta$ for $\beta\geq\alpha$, thus $f(x)<\alpha$.

Looks correct to me

@Pranay Im wondering if my proof is correct.

Is there a specific step you aren’t sure about?

@Pranay I am unsure if my steps require more justification. I emailed my professor (with a previous version of this proof) and he said that there needs to be more justification. The previous proof didn't include the justification for well-definededness. I just want to make sure there are no leaps in logic.
